# How to remove \n, \t out of the word eg "\n\t\t\t\tDay of Week\n\t\t\t" ?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

How to remove `\n`, `\t` of a string.

For example `"\n\t\t\t\tDay of Week\n\t\t\t"` should be viewed as `"Day of Week"` when cucumber reads it from a table.

Getting error as below:

```
RuntimeError: Element do not match for entry : Day of Week
```

The test data is entered as text only but cucumber reads it from the application as `"\n\t\t\t\tDay of Week\n\t\t\t"` and comparison fails.

What needs to be done exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way:

```
 p "\n\t\t\t\tDay of Week\n\t\t\t".strip!
 # >> "Day of Week"
```